# Remove DEFINER clause from MySQL Dumps

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL dump of one of my databases. In it, there are DEFINER clauses which look like,

```
"DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`"
```

Namely, these DEFINER clauses are on my CREATE VIEW and CREATE PROCEDURE statements. Is there a way to remove these DEFINER clauses from my dump file?

Comment: A bug was reported years ago, but it looks abandoned:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=24680

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to ignore adding `DEFINER`s to the dump. But there are ways to remove them after the dump file is created.

1. Open the dump file in a text editor and replace all occurrences of `DEFINER=root@localhost` with an empty string ""
2. [Edit the dump (or pipe the output) using `perl`:](http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/removing-definer-from-mysql-dump/)

   ```
   perl -p -i.bak -e "s/DEFINER=\`\w.*\`@\`\d[0-3].*[0-3]\`//g" mydatabase.sql
   ```
3. [Pipe the output through `sed`:](http://oksoft.blogspot.in/2008/10/mysqldump-backups-and-transfers.html)

   ```
   mysqldump ... | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' > triggers_backup.sql
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the response! So in my text editor, would I replace the entire 'DEFINER=root @ localhost' string with ""? Or replace 'root @ localhost'?

Comment: @FastTrack, please remove the entire string.

Comment: What if the dump file is 10G?

Comment: Can someone clarify what the sed regex is doing? The one that is posted above as the answer doesn't work for me. I've written my own that does work, but I don't even understand how the one posted above would work.

Doesn't 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/', mean match the word DEFINER, followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by =, followed by 0 or more spaces, followed by zero or more characters that are not a literal *, followed by a literal *, and replace it with a literal *?

I don't see how that would match DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`

Comment: @bpeikes, your assessment is right, but this regular expression works on statements like `/*!50017 DEFINER=\`root\`@\`localhost\`*/` and essentially removes the DEFINER statement between asterisks.

Comment: @sxalexander - so this only works in cases where the "DEFINER" statement is in a comment?

Comment: @bpeikes as far as I can tell, yes.  These worked for my case.

Comment: I suggest to mention that instead of removing the DEFINER it can be set to CURRENT_USER like that: `sed -E 's/DEFINER=`[^`]+`@`[^`]+`/DEFINER=CURRENT_USER/g' dump.sql > new_dump.sql` It has the advantage of keeping restrictions / access control.

Comment: on MacOS I'm getting the following error `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence`

Comment: The `sed` command does not remove DEFINER clause from procedures and functions. Here is the enhanced version that handles views, triggers, procedures and functions:

`sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE/' | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*FUNCTION/FUNCTION/'`

Comment: if data is dumped and it contains a string with `DEFINER=*`, this will modify the entry. it is unbelievable that mysqldump does not support anything appropriate

Comment: `sed` snippet does not work for procedures. it works for triggers only.

Comment: FYI --- although it was not the case at the time of this answer, MySQL > 5.6 now ships with a mysqldump(1) that supports "--skip-definer" as an option: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#option_mysqlpump_skip-definer

Comment: No, it's not mysqldump, but mysql**p**ump who has --skip-definer.

Comment: @VladimirStrugatsky's answer is good, I wonder if this might be a bit better way to handle it.   `|  sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/; s/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*PROCEDURE/PROCEDURE/; s/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*FUNCTION/FUNCTION/`  use one pipe and the fact you can string the three sed expressions together rather than three separate pipes.

Comment: `sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' -e 's/\sDEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^* ]*\(\s[A-Z]\+\s\)/\1/'`

Comment: With mysqldump 10.17 (10.3.23-MariaDB) 'DEFINER' appears twice, so that this simpler plain-text sed match with no regex features works: `sed '/DEFINER \*\/$/d'`

Comment: In my case, the perl script didn't find `user`@`localhost`.

Comment: The example is `DEFINER=root@localhost`, but then the regex in the perl call appears to be looking for an IP address. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 108):

You can remove using SED

```
sed -i 's/DEFINER=[^*]*\*/\*/g' mydump.sql
```

In MacOS:

```
sed -i '' 's/DEFINER=[^*]*\*/\*/g' mydump.sql
```

Comment: What is going on here in MacOS to be different?

Comment: The manpage for sed on mac says this:

`-i extension` "Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc."

Comment: Nice to know that, @Chad. I'm using sed like this in mac for 5+ years now. I never had problems with space or corrupted files. But of course, is something to consider. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I've never run into those issues on Mac either. Just thought I would clarify since @Alex asked :)

Comment: it's working fine for me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 83):

Since mysql version 5.7.8 you can use the `--skip-definer` option with **mysqlpump** (not **mysqldump**), e.g.:

```
mysqlpump --skip-definer -h localhost -u user -p yourdatabase
```

See updated mysql manual at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#option_mysqlpump_skip-definer

Comment: For whoever wonders what's the difference between `mysqldump` and `mysqlpump` - here is related question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118846/mysqldump-vs-mysqlpump

Comment: I have phpMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench installed. How do I execute this command on Windows?

Comment: (after some tests: -1) It uses `information_schema.user`, and this isn't always readable for all users

Answer (score 28):

I used these ideas to strip the DEFINER clause from my own mysqldump output, but I took a simpler approach:

Just remove the `!` before the code and DEFINER, and the rest of the comment becomes a regular comment.

Example:

```
/*!50017 DEFINER=`user`@`111.22.33.44`*/
```

is rendered helpless, as little as doing this ..

```
/* 50017 DEFINER=`user`@`111.22.33.44`*/
```

The easiest regexp, though, is to remove the ! and the numbers

```
mysqldump | /usr/bin/perl -pe 's/\!\d+ DEFINER/DEFINER/' > dumpfile.sql
```

That removes `!#### DEFINER` and replaces with DEFINER ... you could remove DEFINER too, it doesn't really matter - once the "!" is gone

Comment: Awesome and elegant solution!

Answer (score 20):

As per the other's recommendations, here is an example of how to remove the DEFINER from the dump, after the dump has finished:

```
mysqldump -u user --password='password' -h localhost database | grep -v "50013 DEFINER" > dump.sql
```

Comment: For triggers, the lines look like    
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`user`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 trigger my_triggername BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW .... */;;    and `grep -v` will drop those lines entirely. (although 50017 != 50013)

Answer (score 15):

As others mentioned stripping the definer with any kind of regular expression is not too complex.
But the other examples stripped the view definitions for me.

This is the regular expression which worked for me:

```
sed -e 's/DEFINER=[^ ]* / /'
```

Comment: Doesn't work with triggers - removes also the `*/`. MySQL 5.6.31.

Answer (score 12):

For an automated solution, you could look at `mysqlmigrate`. It's a Bash wrapper around `mysqldump` which allows you to migrate databases and ignore the DEFINER statements. Example:

```
$ mysqlmigrate -u root -p pass --ignore-definer from_db to_db
```

http://thesimplesynthesis.com/post/mysqlmigrate (or [GitHub](https://github.com/josephdpurcell/mysqlmigrate))

Otherwise, yes, a command like Abhay points out is needed:

```
$ mysqldump -u root -ppass the_db | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]*\*/\*/' > the_db.sql
```

Answer (score 8):

You should look the answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/how-do-i-change-the-definer-of-a-view-in-mysql/29079#29079

The best way in my opinion to address this problem, is not adding an extra parse of string with sed or grep or any other, instead mysqldump is able to generate a good dump by adding --single-transaction

Comment: Why downvoted? Why this answer is not considered useful?

Comment: Your response still needs about 90 upvotes to get the position it deserves. You have mine :)

Comment: I just spent the past 4 hours trying to dump a database. Cant believe it was something so simple! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Another option on OSX to remove definers in-file:

```
sed -i '' 's/DEFINER=`[^`][^`]*`@`[^`][^`]*`//g' file.sql
```

Answer (score 5):

A quick way to do this is to pipe the output of [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) through [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to remove the `DEFINER` statements wrapped in conditional comments. I use this to remove `DEFINER` from `CREATE TRIGGER` statements, but you can tweak the condition comment version number in the regex to suit your purposes.

```sh
mysqldump -u user --password='password' -h localhost database | \
  sed 's/\/\*!50017 DEFINER=`.*`@`.*`\*\///'
```

Comment: A slightly more readable sed statement: sed "s/DEFINER(.*?)FUNCTION/FUNCTION/"

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it helps but I use SQLyog Community Edition, available at: -

https://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/wiki/Downloads

When dumping sql or copying to another database it allows you to 'Ignore DEFINER'

It is free and provides the basic functionality that a lot of people require

There is also a paid version available from: -

https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog

Cheers

Comment: Rather than just flag as 'not useful' perhaps it would be more useful if you reply with why you feel it is not useful?

Answer (score 4):

Best way of dumping and restoring without problems:

#### MYSQL DUMP

```
mysqldump -h HOST -u USER -pPASSWORD --single-transaction --quick --skip-lock-tables --triggers --routines --events DATABASE | gzip > "DATABASE.sql.gz" &
```

#### MYSQL RESTORE

```
gunzip DATABASE.sql.gz

sed -i 's/DEFINER=[^ ]* / /' DATABASE.sql
sed -i 's/SET @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN = @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN;/ /' DATABASE.sql
sed -i 's/SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;/ /' DATABASE.sql
sed -i 's/SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED='';/ /' DATABASE.sql
sed -i 's/SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN = @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN;/ /' DATABASE.sql

mysql -h HOST -u USER -pPASSWORD < DATABASE.sql
```

Comment: For me just the very first `sed` solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

For me, this works: `perl -p -i.bak -e "s/DEFINER=[^ |\s]*//g" yourdump.dmp`.
This removed DEFINER=root@localhost from my dump, on each create procedure statment

Answer (score 3):

if you already exported that sql file, you can change DEFINER inside that file by executing:

```
sed 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//g' -i your_dumpfile.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace all of your definer users with CURRENT_USER.  In my gradle script that creates the backup, my replace script looks like:

```
ant.replaceregexp(file: "$buildDir/sql/setupDB.sql", match: "`${project.ext.prod_db_username}`@`%`", replace: "CURRENT_USER", byline: true);
```

which really is just calling ANT.  Then you won't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete working solution to remove DEFINER information for `MySQL 5.6.x` and Linux.(Tested on `CentOS 6.5`).

Usaually we have to replace following entries from Mysql dump(if taken along with data and triggers/routines/functions).

```
/*!50013 DEFINER=`MYSQLUSER`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
/*!50013 DEFINER=`MYSQLUSER`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
CREATE DEFINER=`MYSQLUSER`@`%` PROCEDURE `PROCEDURENAME`(
CREATE DEFINER=`MYSQLUSER`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `PROCEDURENAME`(
CREATE DEFINER=`MYSQLUSER`@`%` FUNCTION `FUNCTIONNAME`(
CREATE DEFINER=`MYSQLUSER`@`localhost` FUNCTION `FUNCTIONNAME`(
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`MYSQLUSER`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `TRIGGERNAME`
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`MYSQLUSER`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `TRIGGERNAME`
```

The dump was taken with below mysqldump command.

```
mysqldump -uMYSQLUSER -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME -R > dbdump.sql
```

The required dump file with no DEFINER information can be obtained with below three commands.

```
Command-1    
sed -i 's|DEFINER=[^*]*\*|\*|g' [PATH/]dbdump.sql

Command-2
find -name [PATH/]dbdump.sql | xargs perl -pi -e "s/ DEFINER=\`MYSQLUSER\`@\`localhost\`//"

Command-3
find -name [PATH/]dbdump.sql | xargs perl -pi -e "s/ DEFINER=\`MYSQLUSER\`@\`%\`//"
```

If the dump file is in your current folder then ignore [PATH/].

If data in tables is very huge then take the dump in two files, in one dump file take the dump with data and in other dump file on take the dump of the scripts only (Triggers/Functions/Procedures.) and run the above three commands on 2nd dump(scripts) file.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, one possible solution is to replace the usernames in DEFINER clauses to CURRENT_USER.
Note that we must take into account DEFINER in both plain SQL statements and in special comments, like in the following examples:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION...
/*!50013 DEFINER=`MYSQLUSER`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
/*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/
```

So, for me, what works is this:

```
mysqldump <my-options> | sed -E 's/DEFINER=[^ *]+/DEFINER=CURRENT_USER/g' > dumpfile.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

On Linux machines you can use this one-liner:

```
mysql -uuser -ppwd -A --skip-column-names -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW CREATE VIEW ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine IS NULL and table_schema like 'mydb%'" | mysql -uuser -ppwd -A --skip-column-names | sed -rn 's/.*?VIEW ([^\s]+?) (AS .*?)\s([^\s]+?)\s([^\s]+?)/DROP VIEW \1;\nCREATE VIEW \1 \2;/p' | mysql -uuser -ppwd -A --skip-column-names
```

You have only to replace strings in bold with your DB user credentials and database name / like pattern.

More info here: https://blog.novoj.net/posts/2014-05-16-recreate-mysql-views-without-definer-one-liner-solution-linux/

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get it working under Windows:

Install http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ to have **sed** in the command line and add it to the Windows *PATH: D:\programs\GetGnuWin32\bin;*

```
sed -i "s|DEFINER=`mydbuser`@`%%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER||g" "D:/prod_structure.sql"

sed -i "s|DEFINER=`mydbuser`@`%%`||g" "D:/prod_structure.sql"

mysqldump -P{port} -h{host} -u{user} -p{password} --routines --no-data --lock-tables=false database_prod > D:\prod_structure.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for the hints.
Being lazy, I wrote a script named: "MYsqldump" :

```
DB=$1
HOST=$2
USER=$3
MYSQLDUMP='/usr/bin/mysqldump'
PARAMS="--complete-insert --disable-keys=0 --extended-insert=0 --routines=0 --skip-comments"
DAY=`date +%d`
MONTH=`date +%m`
YEAR=`date +%Y`
FILE=$DB.$DAY-$MONTH-$YEAR.sql

    if (( $# < 3 )) ; then
        echo ""
        echo "usage: MYsqldump <db> <host> <user>"
        echo ""
        exit 1
    fi

    $MYSQLDUMP -h $HOST -u $USER -p  $PARAMS $DB | grep -v '/*!50013 DEFINER' > $FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

For something like:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`mydb`@`localhost` FUNCTION `myfunction`() RETURNS int(11)
begin
(...)
end ;;
```

Try this:

```
mysqldump --force --routines --opt --user=myuser --databases mydb | sed -e 's/DEFINER=`.*`@`.*`\ //g'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. open your database with any editor, I used with notepad++,
2. find all test that `DEFINER=root@localhost`
   and replace it with nothing(`""`) IE. delete it.

Then you can import it to the any host that you want.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest regex that works for me with all objects is:

```
sed 's/DEFINER=[^ ]*`//' ...
```

Note that `quote-names` has to be `TRUE` (which is by default).

Hope that in newer versions the switch `--skip-definer` introduced in mysqlpump in version 5.7 comes to mysqldump, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have used PowerShell script to remove all the lines with `DEFINER`:

get-content $file_in_full_path | select-string -pattern $line_string_delete -notmatch | Out-File -width 1000000000 -Encoding Default $file_out_full_path

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was working for me, so I needed to write my own regex.

1. Try to dump your database into file, `cat` whole file and `grep` only your definer statements to see them.

   cat file.sql | grep -o -E '.{,60}DEFINER.{,60}'
2. Write your regex
3. Pipe your dump into sed with this regex. For example mine statement is:

   mysqldump  | sed -E 's//*!500[0-9][0-9] DEFINER=.+?*///' | sed -E 's/DEFINER=`?[^ ]+?`?@`?[^ ]+?` ?//'
4. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

remove_definers.bat:

```
@echo off
(for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%a in (dumpfile.sql) do (
 if "%%b"=="" (echo %%a) else (
  echo %%b | find "DEFINER" > null && echo %%a %%c || echo %%a %%b %%c
 )
)) > dumpfile_nodefiners.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19707173/1488762, I suspect the following may perform better on very large databases - modify the definer at the end, rather than performing additional regex processing on every line:

```
mysqldump myDB > dump.sql
cat >> dump.sql << END
SELECT CONCAT("ALTER DEFINER=`youruser`@`host` VIEW ", 
table_name, " AS ", view_definition, ";") 
FROM information_schema.views 
WHERE table_schema='myDB';
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for my future reference, `sd` version.

```
mysqldump ... | sd 'DEFINER=.*?\*' '*' > file.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for removing `DEFINER` tested on my MariaDB 10.3:

```
mysqldump | grep -v -P 'SQL SECURITY DEFINER \*/$' | perl -pe 's/(?<=^\/\*!50003 CREATE\*\/ )\/\*!50017 DEFINER=`.+`@`.+`\*\/ (?=\/\*!50003 TRIGGER)//'
```

`grep` removes it for views, `perl` removes it for triggers

This solution is is attacker-proof, because it matches start and end of lines. So even if attacker knows you are doing replace of `DEFINER` on your dumps, his `DEFINER` arranged in the data won't be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL file has `DEFINER` occurances (with and) without conditional comments, then you might be interested in this alternative REGEXP.

```
sed -Ei \
    's/DEFINER\s*=\s*(["'\''`]?)[^"'\''`@]+\1\s*@\s*(["'\''`]?)[^"'\''`\*]+\2//g' \
#      [-----1------][----2----][----4----]-5[--6--][----------7------------]
    "$FILE"
```

Explanation:

1. DEFINER {potential whitespace} = {potential whitespace} …
2. … {any potential quote or backtick, captured} …
3. *(break sequence, add escaped single-quote, resume sequence – because we wrap the construct with single-quotes)*
4. … *(username)* {string: no quote or @} …
5. … {use first capturing group – the quote – if any} …
6. … {potential whitespace} @ {potential whitespace} …
7. … {same for host with new capturing group, but also exclude asterisk}.

*(Run without the commented explanation line because that would throw an error)*