# Skip or ignore definers in Mysqldump

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I was wondering if I can prevent mysqldump inserting this commands

```
/*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/
```

Or if I have to do it afterwards with sed, for example

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1917437/477878

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get rid of these comments in a MySQL dump?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916392/how-can-i-get-rid-of-these-comments-in-a-mysql-dump)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question, because it is specifically about DEFINER, which can cause difficulties when importing a dump on a different machine.

It is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446783/remove-definer-clause-from-mysql-dumps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove DEFINER clause from MySQL Dumps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446783/remove-definer-clause-from-mysql-dumps)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This issue has been around since 2006 with no sign of ever being fixed.

I have, however, piped it through grep (linux only) to trim out the definer lines before writing the dump file:

```
mysqldump -u dbuser -p dbname | grep -v 'SQL SECURITY DEFINER' > dump.sql
```

A bit of a mouthful (or keyboardful?) but I think it's the only way.