# Fatal error when moving pimcore from a server to local

Tags: localhost, server, transfer, pimcore

I moved all my **pimcore** files plus the database from a server to my localhost and made the necessary changes in `website/var/config/system.xml`.
Admin is working but the frond end is showing an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getFielddefinitions() on a non-object in /var/www/html/pimcore/pimcore/models/Object/Localizedfield/Resource.php on line 179
```

This line of code produces the error:

```
$this->model->getClass()->getFielddefinition("localizedfields")->getFielddefinitions()
```

The system requirements and file permissions are correct.

For testing purpose I installed a new **pimcore** project on my local system and it's working perfectly.

Can I make any changes in my **Database**?
How can I run my project successfully on local?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is happen when there are already objects present using the class.

**Solution**

1. Login to backend as Admin.
2. Go to `Settings > Object > Classes`
3. For each of the classes in the left tree, click on them and then hit **Save** in the bottom right. (If unable to save just create a new class by hit the button **Add new class** )

Now try to load the frondend. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Pimcore uses database views for storing objects data. When exporting database, in views definitions there will be also SECURITY DEFINER.

`` /*!50013 DEFINER=`prod-user`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */ ``

1. OPTION: Vinot VT solution should work
   You can acchive same with running command:

`php pimcore/cli/console.php deployment:classes-rebuild`

2. OPTION: Use same database username on your local env 'prod-user', which is  useful if you will import prod database a lot
3. OPTION: replace  DEFINER=`prod-user`@`%` with DEFINER=`local-user`@`%` before importing database

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- set <debug>1</debug> in config.xml - this should show error
- if it wasn't helped, check apache and/or php error log.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the actual error (as Vinod has already pointed out).

I could speculate, though:

Are the database credentials (aka the DB username) identical? 
If not you might need to remove the SECURITY DEFINER from the DB Dump. 
See: [Remove DEFINER clause from MySQL Dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446783/remove-definer-clause-from-mysql-dumps) for hints on how to do that.

Another source of error might be the cache. Are you using the default file-based Pimcore cache?
If this is the case, try removing all files from website/var/cache and website/var/tmp

Let us know how that turned out.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's a provisional answer. Not good enough for an upvote, but it proposes solutions to the problem.