# Using triggers with different users (MySQL error 1449)

Tags: triggers, mysql

**Question:** How can I export the database contents (including triggers) from my dev system and import the data to the live server without running into error 1449 when a trigger gets triggered?

In a recent php project I am making extensive use of mysql triggers but ran into a problem when deploying my database from dev to live system.

E.g. one of my triggers is defined as follows (output generated by using `mysqldump`)

```
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER update_template BEFORE UPDATE ON template
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET new.mod_date := now();
END */;;
DELIMITER ;
```

That trigger was defined on my dev system using the user **root`@`localhost** which creates the `DEFINER=root@localhost` clause in above statement.

**root@localhost** does not exist as a user on the live server which causes the following error when ever the trigger gets triggered (e.g. by using `update templates set...`) by the live systems user

> 1449: The user specified as a definer('root'@'localhost') does not exist

Currently I use `mysqldump --add-drop-table --user=root -p my_project > export.sql` for export and `mysql -u devuser -p my_project < export.sql` for importing data.

Export/import works flawless. The error occurs only in cases when I manipulate the data via sql and a trigger gets involved.

**Edit:**

MySQL version is 5.5.47 (live and dev)

Comment: What versions of MySQL uses?. You can use [`--skip-definer`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#option_mysqlpump_skip-definer) since version 5.7.8 of MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, unfortunately not an option for me but added it to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446783/remove-definer-clause-from-mysql-dumps/

Answer (score 1):

Once you've exported to `export.sql`, next you'll need to sanitize your trigger lines using regex via sed, like this:

`sed -i -- 's/^..!50003\sCREATE.....!50017\sDEFINER=.root...[^`]*`.....!50003\s\([^;]*\)/CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER \1/g;s/^\s*\([^\*]*;\{0,1\}\)\s\{0,1\}\*\/;;$/\1;;/g' export.sql`

This works on Linux, but if you're on Mac OS X, the built-in sed command won't work. You'll need to first `brew install gnu-sed`, then use **gsed** instead of **sed** in the above command.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the trigger that caused the problem didn't have the `BEGIN` and `END` statements. So I applied the corresponding `DROP TRIGGER` and `CREATE TRIGGER`, after that I made again a backup that latter restored without problems. i.e:

```
DROP TRIGGER `incorrect_trg1`;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `incorrect_trg1` BEFORE INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
SET NEW.col = DATE_FORMAT(NEW.col,'%Y%m');
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following sed command to remove the DEFINER part from the dump file and then import it to your live server.

```
sed 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]*`@`[^`]*`//' -i dumpfile.sql
```

The triggers will then be created by the user importing the dump file by default.