# Export from phpMyAdmin minus user names?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to export a database to text in phpMyAdmin without the `DEFINER` and other clauses that show my admin user name and IP? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the source code of phpMyAdmin - turns out it simply takes the output of a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` query, which unfortunately comes with the `DEFINER` and other clauses. One example in the pma source, in the method `PMA_getTableDef()`:

`$result = PMA_DBI_try_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE ' . PMA_backquote($db) . '.' . PMA_backquote($table));`

In other words can't remove them through phpMyAdmin but there's plenty of command line tools that can help you remove them, such as answered here: [Remove DEFINER clause from MySQL Dumps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446783/remove-definer-clause-from-mysql-dumps)