# escape CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` when backup from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

When I export any database from phpmyadmin usually mysql following definer for `VIEWS` and `FUNCTIONS` .

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION
```

```sql
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `
```

Is there anything that can be done to avoid that??

Comment: it is usually no problem, as the backup would restore also the users with thier privileges. and so you would not notice it

Comment: @nbk I am having trouble importing into another device with a different user,

Comment: you will have to remove it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446783/remove-definer-clause-from-mysql-dumps

Answer (score 0):

Better try this

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=CURRENT_USER SQL SECURITY INVOKER
```